# Using QGraphicsView to display a local map

Tags: qt, dictionary, coordinates, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I'm trying to use QGraphicsView in order to display a map image and draw some items on top of it. The map boundaries are in a Cartesian coordinate system, for example NE(-500,200) to SW(600,-350). I know how to map image pixels <--> my coordinate system.

I would have to achieve the following:

1. Add a map image to the scene and tell Qt how to map the actual image pixels to scene coordinates.
2. Add graphic items at their real position, e.g. (-100,200)

Doing (2) is straightforward - simply add the item to the scene. How do I achieve (1)? what should I do after I call scene->addPixmap()?

**Edit** - A few clarifications:

- I'm mapping an indoor area of a few hundred meters
- The map will change at real-time in two ways:

  - The map gets bigger every few seconds
  - The graphic items move, change colors, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the pixmap into a QGraphicsPixmapItem and place it in the scene.
2. Call [setScale()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale) to map the QGraphicsPixmapItem so 1 meter maps to 1 unit in the scene coordinate. ie. setScale(0.1) if 10 pixels in the pixmap equal 1 meter.
3. Update the pixmap and scale of the item as needed.
4. Call [fitInView()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) to zoom to the pixmap.
5. Place other graphic items in the scene. Treat the units of the scene coordinate as meters.
6. ...
7. Profit! :)

Comment: Thanks! It works but I'm not sure about the fitInView() part - the image gets stretched and looks distorted.